# `String.prototype.at` is not implemented in all browsers. Is there a @babel/plugin that will transform this down to ES5 javascript?

Tags: javascript, babel-plugin

At the time of this question `String.prototype.at` is not implemented in all browsers.

I would like to use the `at` function on the String prototype within a React app that uses babel to transform modern ecmascript into older more browser compatible versions of javascript.

I have been unsuccessful in finding a babel plugin that would do this for me.

Is there a @babel/plugin that will transform the String prototype `at` function down to more browser compatible ES5 javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Babel is for syntax-level transformations, not browser API polyfills.

You can consider using a polyfill service like [Polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v3/), or alternatively, simply use the [polyfill code from the relevant proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-relative-indexing-method#polyfill).

Comment: what about `@babel/polyfill`? Will this one work? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill/ It seems to suggest that it polyfills native prototypes and instance methods

Comment: @skellertor Given that there's a big notice up the top saying "deprecated in favor of core.js", it may or may not have newer features like `String#at`. I'm assuming core.js would have it, though.